# Best algorithm to merge pair of connected indices

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, sorting, merge

I have following problem definition and searching on an efficient way (a dirty way already found):

I have a set of correspondences whith integer IDs, e.g.:

(0,9)
(1,5)
(9,2)
(2,3)

what i want is a set of arrays which all have connected correspondecnes included, in my example that would be

(0,9,2,3)
(1,5)

My dataset is really big so i need it very efficient, best in C++ and tbb. 
What i currently did and what works (but is in fact slow and single threadded):

```
struct point
{
  std::set<size_t> others;
};

std::map<size_t, point> globalList;

//globalList is filled with input data set, for my example:

globalList[0].others.insert(0);
globalList[0].others.insert(9);

globalList[1].others.insert(1);
globalList[1].others.insert(5);

globalList[9].others.insert(9);
globalList[9].others.insert(2);

globalList[2].others.insert(2);
globalList[2].others.insert(3);

bool changed;
do
{
changed = false;
for (auto it1 = globalList.begin(); it1 != globalList.end(); ++it1 )
{
   for (auto it2 = it1 ; it2 != globalList.end(); ++it2 )
   {
      if (it2 == it1 )
        continue;

      auto findIt = it2->second.others.find(it1->first);

      bool merge = false;
      if( findIt != it2->second.others.end())
      {
        merge = true;
      }
      else
      {
        for( auto otherIt = it1->second.others.begin(); otherIt != it1->second.others.end(); ++otherIt )
        {
          findIt = it2->second.others.find(*otherIt );
          if (findIt != it2->second.others.end())
          {
            merge = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if(merge )
      {
         it1->second.others.insert(it2->second.others.begin(), it2->second.others.end());
         auto it2remove = it2;
         --it2;
         globalList.erase(it2remove );

         changed= true;
       }
     }
   }
  } while (changed);
}`
```

any suggestions, tips (links to algorithms, e.g. in boost) or implementations would be great....

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is basically find [connected components in a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms). In your case you are starting with a set of edges (each pair is an edge).

[There is for example the boost graph library, which has an implementation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/graph/doc/connected_components.html)

Comment: thanks for that hint. I thought that there must be a name for such problems but did not know the correct term to search for.... i will have a look at it...

Comment: @Gerald In the link to the boost library documentation there is also a link to a simple usage example which seems quite nice. The boost graph library's generality/complexity can be a bit daunting sometimes.

Comment: what a shame: My computation time on my big data set with my above solution: 148s

Comment: and with boost: 0.149s

Comment: @Gerald There is also a parallel version of the boost graph library, but I haven't used it and it seems to be based on multiple processes rather than threads. I missed that you were asking for multithreading support.

Comment: since reading in my data (and generate global graph nodes UIDs from more local IDs) takes much longer than computation with single threadded boost its more than ok.... I did not supposed that it would be possible to compute it below 5-10 seconds (which would be ok for me) and not i am on 0.1seconds so no need to further dig into something.....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like finding the longest path in trees. What do you do with loops ? I would try with a tree or graph storage of your items.

Comment: my idea was to look around and find same indeces and then merge them until there is nothing to merge any more..... not best but initial solution...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **Union Find** or **[Disjoint Set Data Structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)**

An efficient implementation along **with a great tutorial** can be found [here](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/disjoint-set-union-union-find/).

Comment: sounds also great, will be my second test after my test with boost (already implemented and running) from Eichhörnchen

Comment: since i tried now Eichhörnchens implemention with same correct result on my big data set and get a perfromance change from 148 seconds to 0.149 seconds i will keep using that solution (0.149 are very great and fast enough for me). But your link looks also very great and interesting....thanks

Comment: @Gerald Boost C++ will be most likely using the most optimal version of the best available algorithm. I posted the link so that you could have a look at what is going on behind the scenes. Also in your case you wont even need to use boost. You can make a graph and simple do [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to get the job done. If you want I can post the code for you. __But using boost C++ will the best option for all real world application as they are highly optimised.__

Comment: since my problem is real world application and since i usually have nothing to do with graphs its ok for me to dummy use boost (and i already use boost in my app, so its not an afford for me to use that external lib). From the theoretical/scientific background your answer is better, yes....